# Define an interface using Multiple bound Types of Java Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am relatively scaled at beginner level of knowledge in Advanced Java Generics. I wanted to define a interface something like this

```
public interface Transformer {
 <T extends String & List<String>> T transform(String input) throws            
  IOException;
}
```

My Implementation Class A is shown as below:

```
public Class A implements Transformer{
   ....
   ....

  @Override
  public <T extends String & List<String>> T transform(String input)     throws IOException {
     String response = "a";
    return response; // compilation error "Incompatible Types: Required T but found java.lang.String"
   }

}
```

What I want to have : The implementation class should be able to pass a String input and return type can be String or a List. The implementation class is totally given freedom to choose either of the return types.

Question:
1. Why is the compilation error "Incompatible Types: Required T but found java.lang.String" is showing up?

Comment: the return value of the transform method needs to extend a String (which it cant since String is final) and implement the List<String> interface. I highly doubt thats something you wanted... you should rephrase your question so that your target is clear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood intersection types.

The definition you have means: T is a String `and` `List<String>`, and not String `OR` `List<String>`, which is not possible because String is not a `List<String>` and nothing can extend a `String` and `List<String>` because `String` is `final`.

Such a definition makes sense if you have an intersection between two interfaces because Java support multiple interface inheritance, or one implementation and multiple interfaces since a class can extend another implementation and implement multiple interfaces.

Because a `List<String>` is capable of having zero or more Strings, you can make your method just return `List<String>`.

Comment: Appreciate for your response. I understood your answer.I was actually looking to see if Java Generics has an option to support like T extends String or List<String>. It might be dumb but looking around the docs and tutorials. How to work around to define a interface which accepts String input and returns a response of type String or Collection ?

Comment: @saripallivskp As I said, a Collection is capable of having zero or more values.